# Windows Azure AppFabric ACS - Adding custom STS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, appfabric, wif

I've currently got Windows Azure AppFabric system set up and running with my own registered Namespace, in which uses the Google/Yahoo/Windows Live STS providers. That all works fine, I can use them and login to my application. Easy.

However, I can't find anything in any way useful on the web that related to adding my own STS to this list from a 3rd party supplier. I've read that it's possible, and it's the last hurdle I'm stuck on here - replacing the Google/Yahoo/Windows Live STS with the ones I need my application to authenticate with. I cannot find anywhere in the STS control panel to allow for this (AppFabric Labs).

Has anyone got any experience with this and can show guidance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add new Identity Providers in two ways:

1- Use the "Identity Providers" menu option on the left, then pick your options. They are typically labeled "ADFS v2.0" (this is the one you use for any WS-Federation STS including the STS WIF will generate for you inside Visual Studio), "Facebook", etc

2- Use the Management API.

For what you are doing seems like #1 is the way to go initially. There's one notable exception. OpenID identity providers can only be added programatically at this time.

Comment: Nice answer, but just to clear this up - if I'm getting an STS from PingFederate (a high profile SSO company), then I'd have to add that through ADFS V2.0 even when the STS wouldn't really be Active Directory based?

Comment: I can see what you mean now, which is great, however just one more to finish this off fully - the WS-Federation metadata URL for Ping Identity, do you have any idea where I can obtain this? Apologies if that's asking for too much, your answer is going to be marked as accepted either way.

Comment: If your STS (PingFederate) supports WS-Federation (which I'm pretty sure it does), then the answer is yes. Try importing the WS-FederationMetadata doc offered by Ping and see what happens.

Comment: We posted comments at the same time :-). Unfortunately I'm not familiar at all with Ping products.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go about doing that and see what I can get out of Ping :)

Comment: There's useful info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/11/23/ad-fs-2-0-step-by-step-guide-federation-with-ping-identity-pingfederate.aspx "AD FS 2.0 Step-by-Step Guide: Federation with Ping Identity PingFederate" It's ADFS centric rather than ACS but the basics still apply.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen that one, which is helpful - but my final step is concerning in terms of integreating with PingIdentity - he's the follow-up question if you have any experience with it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485078/windows-azure-acs-with-pingidentity-sts