# Windows Azure ACS with PingIdentity STS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wif, pingfederate

This is going to be a question really for someone who has knowledge with PingIdentity and ACS, which could be pretty limited.

I've got my ACS set up, all working fine and I know how to add a custom STS (PingIdentity) but I can't find any of the PingIdentity Federation MetaData (FederationMetaData.xml) to authenticate with.

Apparently our current system's workflow is such:

Us -> Our PingIdentity server -> Supplier -> Supplier's PingIdentity server -> Route token back to us.

Would I have to use our local PingIdentity Federation MetaData as the STS in order to achieve what I'm looking for (same scenario, but with ACS)? And where can I find this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document may help:

[AD FS 2.0 Step-by-Step Guide: Federation with Ping Identity PingFederate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/11/23/ad-fs-2-0-step-by-step-guide-federation-with-ping-identity-pingfederate.aspx)

albeit that it's ADFS rather than ACS (although the principles are similar).

Page 12 shows you need access to the PingFederate administrative console. Do you have that?

Comment: Ahhh! I saw that page but didn't actually click on the full document, just the other links it provided (doh!) - I'll accept this answer if the below one does not prove more personally more in-depth about the situation I'm facing :) Rated up for now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve Active or Passive Requester Profile with PingFed and ACS? Just trying to clarify which type of meta-data you're looking for.

Comment: I didn't realise there were two forms of PingFed authentication; there's a username/password required that doesn't link to AD on our clients data storage (where the user's are held) so I'm guessing Passive?

Comment: I saw your new thread you started about exporting signed meta-data. I answered your question over there.